# How to set print format on Carbon object ? not globaly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have code like:

```
$value = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value)->format('m/d/Y');
```

and function format return string, I want to set format but return Carbon object, something like:

```
$value = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value)->formatReturnObject('m/d/Y');
```

Comment: oh my good I get 2 minuses but question is very good, you can see my solution on answer....

Comment: Obviously it isn't a good question if your found the answer yourself quickly, you're suppose to be doing your own research first.

Comment: I was researching 1 hour and sudenly find a solution. stackoverflow was my last option.

Comment: I have 45 question, some my stupid question have 5 votes up, I think this is my best question and this one have 3 votes down...

Comment: I think your question is voted down, because you didn't write clearly what you are trying to achieve. **I want to set format but return Carbon object** is not very clear to me at least.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution quickly :

```
$birthday= \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $birthday);
$birthday->setToStringFormat('m/d/Y');
return $birthday;
```

If I run this :

```
echo $birthday;
print_r($birthday);
```

Output is:

```
06/17/1988
Carbon\Carbon Object
(
    [date] => 1988-06-17 07:55:58.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
```

Comment: note: `->setToStringFormat()` appears to be deprecated